# How to include js and css files in rails - correct syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use Bootstrap Combobox for rails.

The instructions say that:

---

*"You will need two files included in your HTML in order for this to
work:

js/bootstrap-combobox.js

css/bootstrap-combobox.css*

---

I realise that they need to go in the application js and application css respectively, but I think that I'm getting the syntax wrong because I'm getting an error.

This is how I'm adding to application.css.scss:

```
* require css/bootstrap-combobox.css
```

This is how I'm adding to application.js:

```
//= require bootstrap-combobox
```

Comment: This plugin might not work with scss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What error are you getting?

Without knowing the exact error, here's what I suggest:

After you make sure you have a file in your `assets/stylesheets` named `bootstrap-combobox.css`, you want your require statement to look like this:

`*= require bootstrap-combobox`

Your `require` statement looks fine for the JS assuming you have the file in the `assets/javascripts` folder.

You can also use `//= require_tree .` and `*= require_tree .` to require all files in your `javascripts` and/or `stylesheets` folders respectively instead as well.

Check out [this section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization) of the Rails asset pipeline for more info.